# How to convert text to date value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 1/2/2015 21:00:00 in a cell A1 and when I do =istext(A1) I get TRUE  and this makes it hard to compare this date to other dates because it is in the Text format.  How can I convert this to a date format so I can compare it to other dates?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula `=DATEVALUE(A1)`.

This takes a text input and converts it to a date.